# How to Properly Reference a Variable in a Class for Use in Another Class?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm self-learning Python 2 and I'm currently working on a OOP Blackjack game.  I want to properly reference a variable in a class for use within another class. So far I have assigned `d = Deck()`, `p = PlayerHand()`, and dealt a card using `d.deal()`, but I can't seem to execute `p.hit()`. The exception is telling me that the variable `single_card` is not defined.

```
import random

rank = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
suit = ['Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Spade']

card_val = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '10':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':1}

class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rank) + ' of ' + str(self.suit)

    def grab_suit(self):
        return self.suit

    def grab_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def draw(self):
        print(self.suit + self.rank)

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []    
        for i in rank:
            for j in suit:
                self.cards.append(Card(i,j))

    def __str__(self):
        return str([str(card) for card in self.cards])

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self):
        single_card = self.cards.pop()
        return single_card

class PlayerHand(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = []

    def hit(self):
        self.hit = self.value.append(single_card)
```

Comment: Generally on OOP if you want to reference a variable in a class for using in another one you should define it and make a setter method for setting it is value and a getter method for get it is value. and in which class you want your single_card variable be?

Comment: `def hit(self, single_card)` is the quickest resolution

Comment: `self.hit` will always equal `None`, since `self.value.append` always returns `None`.

Comment: Fwiw unless you know for absolutely certain you need to learn legacy Python for a specific reason I strongly suggest learning Python 3 instead.

Comment: conceptually, from just class/object/oo/design perspective (in any language / re: encapsulation), variables in one class aren't directly accessible from another class. You'd have to pass them in via a method or constructor.

Comment: it's "ok" to learn python using python2, since (for some unknown reason) a lot of courses still (for some reason) "require" it, but I'd test against python3 and python2 to keep the code as portable as possible. That in itself is "educational". Python2/3 portability can be a real pain. http://python3porting.com/noconv.html

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Blackjack, you could define a Dealer class that holds the Deck and a list of players

Then, in the Deck class, or preferably in the Dealer class, you can deal into a PlayersHand

```
def deal(self, hand):
    single_card = self.cards.pop()  # or self.deck.deal()
    if hand:  # pass None to this function to draw without dealing 
        hand.value.append(single_card) 
    return single_card

d = Deck()
p = PlayerHand()
d.deal(hand)
```

Alternatively, give the deck to the Player class functions  to have it draw

Answer (score 0):

With your current design, you could grab the single card from an instance of Deck and pass in that card to the player's hand hit method.

```
deck = Deck()
card = deck.deal()
hand = PlayerHand()
hand.hit(card)
```

And change `PlayerHand.hit` to this:

```
class PlayerHand(object):
    ...

    def hit(self, card):
        self.value.append(card)
```

Comment: I don't think you acquire cards when you hit in blackjack

Comment: What do you mean?  The definition of hit in blackjack is taking a card from the dealer.

Comment: Hmm. Must be thinking of something else